# Output of logistic model in R

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to interpret the following type of logistic model:

```
mdl <- glm(c(suc,fail) ~ fac1 + fac2, data=df, family=binomial)
```

Is the output of `predict(mdl)` the expected odds of success for each data point? Is there a simple way to tabulate the odds for each factor level of the model, rather than all the data points?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you mean by cross-tabulating the ORs? Your factors have more than two levels?

Comment: Yes, the factors have 3 and 6 levels respectively. I'm wanting a table of what the predicted odds are for each possible combination of `fac1` and `fac2`.

Comment: Ok, @Bernd's answer is fine with me. Maybe have a look at the `Design` package from Franck Harrell; it has very nice functions along `lrm()` for GLMs and related stuff.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The help pages for

```
predict.glm
```

state: "Thus for a default binomial model the default predictions are of log-odds         (probabilities on logit scale) and ‘type = "response"’ gives the predicted probabilities". So, `predict(mdl)` returns the log(odds), and using "type = "response" returns the predicted probabilities. You might find this toy example instructive:

```
> y <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
> prop.table(table(y))
y
  0   1 
0.3 0.7 
> glm.y <- glm(y~1, family = "binomial")
> ## predicted log(odds)
> predict(glm.y)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
0.8472979 0.8472979 0.8472979 0.8472979 0.8472979 0.8472979 0.8472979 0.8472979 
        9        10 
0.8472979 0.8472979 
> ## predicted probabilities (p = odds/(1+odds))
> exp(predict(glm.y))/(1+exp(predict(glm.y)))
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 
> predict(glm.y, type = "response")
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7
```

Regarding your second question, you might want to check out the effects-package http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/effects/index.html by John Fox; see also his JSS article "Effect Displays in R for Generalised Linear Models" (pp. 8-10).

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!